# When debugging in Emacs how can I signal EOF in the I/O window?

Tags: linux, emacs

When running program which reads from stdio from in bash, I can signal EOF by typing Ctrl-D. When debugging such a program in gdb mode in Emacs, Ctl-D is not recognized in the input/output window. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running it from shell, then either try to press `C-c C-d` that will call `comint-send-eof` function, or if it's really inside program itself, you can try to use `C-q C-d` to send `C-d` as raw key command.

Comment: The second one works if press C-q C-d then enter. Not sure what you mean by the first case - when would this be applicable?

Comment: this really depends on how you're running - it wasn't clear from your question completely.  First key combo will work for shell commands that are executed via `shell`

Comment: OK, thanks have updated my question to make it clearer.